# Will be a ring signature scheme possible to implement at Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, cryptography, serenity, ring-signatures, monero

It's been quite a few days I'm wondering if a [Ring Signature Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature) (like Monero (XMR) has) can be implemented on Ethereum blockchains.

As far as I know, that will be so nice **in order to increase anonymity** (but understanding that it **won't be totally anonymous because the signs will be done by groups ob Pub. Key Hashes, not all of them** (which will make it totally anonymous).

As I see it, the PoW -> PoS pass will be a nice moment to implement that kind of changes.

If someone knows any **paper/article related with that, fill free to share please**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This implementation here demonstrates how to do it in Ethereum using a Smart Contract and Byzantine precompiles:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5e10d764314040b04ac7d96610b9851c8bc02815#code

The corresponding discussion at reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/75rzdn/linkable_ring_signatures_on_ropsten/

Comment: Thanks! So interesting lecture and a very very nice contract code implementing it! Appreciate it!
Do you know about more discussions/papers/articles talking about that?

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a Vitalik's post on where he talks about some of those things.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/15/privacy-on-the-blockchain/

I think it can be interesting to you.

Comment: Interesting lecture (as always on ethereum blog)  but a bit more explanation on the answer will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a multi-signature transactions apparently doesn't go with some goals of ethereum as a whole project and idea.

You can read more from here as this question has been asked here :
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/123

But if you want something on a higher layer you can implement a smart contract that creates the ring transaction signature independently of the nature of transactions itself. ( just saying it Is not that complicated)

Comment: Thanks. But the question is if it will be possible to do. Asking about if merging a ring signature scheme will be possible to merge on the ethereum blockchains. 

The idea of making it on a contract.. I don't know, because the one who deployed it, is someone that is with high probability implicated, and then, no anonymity is happening. Appart of saying that will be crazy to write in Solidity from scrach a Ring Signature Scheme.

Comment: I don't see how the deployer would need to be implicated, it is still up to the contract code to wether to implicate the contract owner or not. And as I said it goes against some of the ethereum goals as a project.