# How to hide the private information of the transaction sender?

Tags: solidity, privacy

I want to implement the following functions in theory through solidity in test chain environment, and it is not required to be implemented in a production environment: a user can initiate a transaction and the miner verifies the transaction. However, during the verification process, the miner knows that the transaction is valid, but does not know the key privacy information such as the address of the sender. I want to know if this can be achieved, or is there a way to achieve a similar effect?

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, at least not with the same functionality as is in use in Ethereum mainnet. Basically there are no secrets in Ethereum blockchain.

However there are various Ethereum variants which have some modified functionality for secrecy, such as Quorum.

Comment: Hi, Lauri! I have read some articles, some one say that you can create the ring transaction signature independently of the nature of transactions itself, whch will help to hide the transaction privacy. I want to know whether it is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Ethereum does not use ring signatures. So it's not possible at the EVM level.

Comment: Is it possible for me to implement a ring signature function through a smart contract to protect user privacy to a certain extent?

Comment: To a certain extent, possibly yes. Here's some info I quickly googled: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48725/will-be-a-ring-signature-scheme-possible-to-implement-at-ethereum